# How to get fixed effects in an FE model in R

Tags: r

In an equation as such:

***log(Pis)=B0+B1log(X1)+B2log(X2)+B3(X3)+e***

for firms i across 25 periods from s=1 to s=25 (panel data).

The output in R for fixed effects only gives me estimates for **X1**, **X2**, and **X3** (all time-varying variables naturally). How do I get the fixed effects?

These are my commands:

```
Y <- cbind(P)
X <- cbind(X1,X2,X3)
pdata <- plm.data(mydata, index=c("i","s"))
between <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model="between")
summary(between)
fd <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model="fd")
summary(fd)
fixed <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, model="within")
summary(fixed)
```

As mentioned before, the summary for the **fixed** command only gives me estimates for $X1$, $X2$, and $X3$. The summary of **fd**, which is *Oneway (individual) effect First-Difference Model*, gives me an intercept. I also get an intercept for **between** (that is *Oneway (individual) effect Between Model* in plm).

Comment: Can you provide your data in `dput()` form as well as the summary tables you get from running those regressions?

Comment: @useR I think I got it. I ran `fixef(fixed)`. I did not get any p-values or anything,though.

Comment: If you want to get helpful answers, it's better that you provide your data. Otherwise, it's very difficult for others to help you.